# Regex: extracting matches preceding a pattern in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I'm trying to extract matches preceding a pattern in R. Lets say that I have a vector consisting of the next elements:

```
my_vector
> [1] "ABCC12|94160"        "ABCC13|150000"       "ABCC1|4363"          "ACTA1|58" 
[5] "ADNP2|22850"         "ADNP|23394"          "ARID1B|57492"        "ARID2|196528"
```

I'm looking for a regular expression to extract all characters preceding the **"|"**. The expected result must be something like this:

```
my_new_vector
> [1] "ABCC12"  "ABCC13"  "ABCC1"  "ACTA1"
```

and so on.

I have already tried using `stringr` functions and regular expressions based on look arounds, but I failed.

I really appreciate your advices and help to solve my issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `trimws` and specify the `whitespace` as a regex that matches the `|` (metacharacter - so escape `\\` followed by one or more character (`.*`)

```
trimws(my_vector, whitespace = "\\|.*")
```